# Why is accuracy score suddenly becoming 1 on using XGBoost?

Tags: xgboost, k-means, accuracy

I am developing a music classification system based on a kaggle dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vatsalmavani/spotify-dataset
I tried using K means classifier to classify the songs into 4 groups for a number of n_neighbours values , but the best accuracy i was able to obtain was 0.5431363971265426 , then i tried using XGboost for the same task to check if the accuracy score was improving and now its jumping straight to 1 , for both the training and testing split , I am not able to understand how this is possible , could someone kindly throw some light on this.[image: Error % for values of n_neighbours from 1 to 101]

This is the error % for 101 (1 to 101) different values of the n_neighbours parameter.

Comment: Into what categories are you trying to classify the music and what hyperparameters are you using for your XGBoost model? It could be that the classification is quite easy given the features, or that the depth of the individual trees is quite high.

Comment: @Oxbowerce
I am trying to classify it based on ['valence','acousticness','danceability','energy','popularity','tempo','instrumentalness']; the above columns from the dataset

Comment: Please provide the code for your training process. It sounds too good to be true that XGBoost achieves 100% on test data. That it achieves 100% on training data is not impossible, as it is a higher capacity model compared to k-means. But it depends on your training parameters, which you have not presented in the question.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question:

- First, why is XGBoost is giving accuracy as 1. The model looks too good to believe. It might be that the model is overfitting on the data.
- Try shuffling the training data.
- Please try to use early_stopping in your XGBoost, so the model will stop training when it gets best score. You can use early stopping over any metric.
- Also try to do some feature selection and model tuning to get better results.
- The result you are getting are probably because you have 1 or 2 columns that are highly correlated to your label (target) column.

Hope I answered your question.